# How do I export feed placed on any Account record in the PDF format?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, controller-extension

Can anyone tell me how we can export feed placed on any account record as PDF. I want to do this via custom Button that will export the feed in as pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your account related feed into `Visualforce` page with `renderAs` attribute value of `pdf`

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
// insert your Account feed code here
</apex:page>
```

This would generate `pdf` file for you